# Use detokenize with command line input that has underscores

Tags: characters, detokenize

I'm calling a script where I give a command line input to LaTeX:

```
pdflatex "\def\myvar{given_test} \input{figures.tex}"
```

And then in the script, I try to use this "given_test" input and print it:

```
\textbf{filename: \myvar}
```

This breaks LaTeX, then I try to use detokenize

```
\textbf{filename: \detokenize{\myvar}}
```

And that just prints the text "\myvar"

The underscore is a necessity, since we are reading from a more complex pipeline that uses them for the file identifiers.

So how do I read what is inside `\myvar` and not break LaTeX.

Comment: Try `\textbf{filename: \expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\myvar}}`

Comment: It works, but it gives a dot instead of the underscore, is understandable, but if it gave the underscores it would be great, care to write it as an answer and then you can get the sweet points?

Comment: @Leonpalafox Changing `\textbf` onto `\texttt` gives underscore in the desired place.

Comment: You can use `\edef\myvar{\detokenize{given_test}}` in the command line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Together with guidelines in [Handling of special LaTeX characters in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38718/5764), you can expand `\myvar` before `\detokenize`-ing it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\def\myvar{given_test}
\begin{document}
\textbf{filename: \detokenize\expandafter{\myvar}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking but I think that the first `\expandafter` is not mandatory (as with `\unexpanded`). Sorry if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @cjorssen You're right: `\detokenize` looks for the opening brace expanding tokens as it goes, so the first `\expandafter` is not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

It shouldn't be difficult to change your pipeline to do

```
pdflatex "\edef\myvar{\detokenize{given_test}}\input{figures.tex}"
```

Example with `figures.tex` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Here's the file name: \texttt{\myvar}

\input{\myvar}

\end{document}
```

and with `given_test.tex` containing

```
Hello World!
```

Compiling with the above command line gives

[image]

so you see that the variable points to the correct file name.

Note that if you need `\myvar` in other fonts than typewriter type, loading

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in the document becomes necessary.