# How to deactivate % as special character?

Tags: tex-core, characters, active-characters

<sub>**Background:** I use `LaTeX` to display data that are automatically produced. I cannot manually change the raw data (since they are frequently updated).</sub>

<sub>But this raw text contains `LaTeX`'s special characters (`_`, `&`, and `%`). This makes compilation fail.</sub>

<sub>I have found in [Handling of special LaTeX characters in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38718/64454) how to tell LaTeX to treat `_` and `&` as "regular" characters. However, `` \catcode`%=12 `` does not work...</sub>

---

**Question:** How to tell LaTeX that the symbol `%` should be considered as a "regular" character?

Of course, defining this behavior globally would make compilation of many packages fail, so this redefinition should be applicable locally/temporarily (e.g. in an `\input`ed `.tex` file).

Comment: \catcode`\%=12 should do.

Comment: To make it local, enclose it and the affected code between `\bgroup` / `\egroup` delimiters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make `%` punctuation character by

```
\catcode`\%=12
```

Answer (score 13):

In ConTeXt you can use ASCII mode by saying `\asciimode`.  This will disable the special meaning of `#$%&^_|~` for the whole document from that point.  You can still have comments with double percent signs.

```
\asciimode
\starttext

#$%&^_|~  %% these are disabled

\ { }     %% these remain enabled

\stoptext
```

If you only want to enable it for a short piece of text, use `\start...\stopasciimode`.

```
\starttext

\startasciimode
  #$%&^_|~  %% these are disabled

  \ { }     %% these remain enabled
\stopasciimode

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5):

A category code assignment is of the form

```
\catcode <number> = <number>
```

(spaces and `=` are optional). The first `<number>` is the character we want to assign the category code (so eight bit in legacy engines, up to `0x10FFFF` for Unicode engines), the second one is the category code (four bit number).

The number can be expressed in any legal form understood by TeX: decimal, octal, hexadecimal or alphabetic. For instance, the usual category code 4 to `&` can be assigned by

```
\catcode 38 = 4    % decimal
\catcode '46 = 4   % octal
\catcode "26 = 4   % hexadecimal
\catcode `& = 4    % alphabetic
```

In order to change the category code of `%`, which is preassigned to 14 when INITEX starts off, so embedded in every format that doesn't change the assignment, we have a problem if we want to use the “alphabetic” representation:

```
\catcode `% = 12
```

cannot work, because the `%` character has not yet been assigned a different category code, so it is still a comment character when the code is being read in. You can do it with the explicit number

```
\catcode 37 = 12
```

because `%` is ASCII 37 (hexadecimal `0x25`). But it would be much handier to use the character! There is an escape to this *cul-de-sac*: an alphabetic constant can also be designed by

```
`\<character>
```

where the backslash must be a character of category code 0 (as usual). In this case the one character control sequence is not interpreted as a macro, but just as the character it is named with. Hence

```
\catcode `\% = 12
```

will work. Similarly, if you want to temporarily change the category code of the backslash to 12 you can do

```
\catcode `\\ = 12
```

(the assignment will be done *after* having input the control sequence `\\` in order to interpret it as an alphabetic constant because of the backquote).

Other characters that must be denoted this way are those with category code 5 (end line), 9 (ignored) or 15 (invalid). Also category code 6 characters are better expressed this way, particularly when the category code assignment is in the replacement text of a macro.

Thus, when you have to change category code of a character (possibly) having category code 0 (escape), 5 (end line), 6 (parameter), 9 (ignored), 14 (comment) or 15 (invalid), use either the decimal form or the escaped form.

Comment: To go a step further in the explanations, see [What are category codes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16412/64454)!