# Create a macro that uses \includepdf{} to include a filename with an underbar?

Tags: windows, pdfpages

I am developing a complex system that does a bunch of things with included PDFs.  So complicated that I want to define a macro. Unfortunately, many of my users have filenames that have spaces and underbars in them.  I haven't been able to figure out how to create a macro that runs `\includepdf` with the filename as a macro that allows files that include spaces.

That is, I want to get this program to work:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
  Including file: #1 (on next page).
  \clearpage
  \includepdf{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\mycommand{demo_include1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

But the errors I get are:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11 \mycommand{demo_include1.pdf}

? ^D
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11 \mycommand{demo_include1.pdf}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on d.log.
```

So how do I fix my LaTeX file?

Comment: Underscores always worked fine for me. You don't need the `\clearpage`. Maybe it only works for images, though.

Comment: Then again, I always load `fontenc`.

Comment: @cfr -- It's this part of the command `Including file: #1 (on next page).` when the `#1` has an underscore in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?  (Note the use of `fontenc`.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  Including file: \detokenize{#1} (on next page).
  \includepdf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\mycommand{demo_include.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does the `fontenc` do?

Comment: Try it without it.

Comment: The `\clearpage` is unnecessary.

Comment: @cfr -- touché. I was focused more on the other part....

Comment: Well my actual code is far more complicated. What you provided works, but I couldn't put the filename (#1) into the `\chapter` as `\chapter{#1}`.  I ended up following the advice at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38718/handling-of-special-latex-characters-in-text

Comment: Ah, OK. (Sometimes examples can be *too* minimal, I guess....) Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Also `\path` from the `url` package should work.