# Underscore in Pathway

Tags: underscore

I'm beginning with Latex and I want to add some JavaCode in it. My source code is in "D:\Eclipse_Projects\Algorithimique\src\s09" but I think the underscore is making trouble.
I use the following code :

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8    ]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings} % Required for insertion of code

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[caption=Methode_FindBug04]{D:/Eclipse_Projects/Algorithimique/src/s09/FindBugs.java}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help? 
Thank

Comment: The underscore in the file name is not a problem, but in the caption text.  [Use e.g. `caption=Methode\_FindBug04`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38718/handling-of-special-latex-characters-in-text).

Comment: I tried to do so, but now I have the following error :Missing $ inserted

Comment: Have you removed the auxiliary file? If not, remove all auxiliary files and try again.

Comment: Still the same error... I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce it using `\lstinputlisting[caption=Methode\_FindBug04]{./Eclipse_Projects/FindBugs.java}` with a very simple `FindBug.java` (only one line with `test` in it). I do not have `D:` so I just used a subdirectory of my working directory.